# C# - How to Delete temporary internet files

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0, temporary-files

I want to clear the temporary Internet files folder completely. The location of the folder, e.g., `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files`, depends on the version of Windows, so it has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this path: [`Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
//for deleting files
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); //delete subdirectories and files
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to kill the process Internet Explore and change the directory attributes and don't go thinking this will work for Index.dat files bacause MS keep changing the rules.

Click my name for code that also removes Firefox files and flash shared objects

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Text;

namespace Fidling
{
    public static class SpywareRemoval
    {
        private static void RemoveSpywareFiles(string RootPath, string Path,bool Recursive)
        {
            string FullPath = RootPath + Path + "\\";
            if (Directory.Exists(FullPath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo DInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FullPath);
                FileAttributes Attr = DInfo.Attributes;
                DInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                foreach (string FileName in Directory.GetFiles(FullPath))
                {
                    RemoveSpywareFile(FileName);
                }
                if (Recursive)
                {
                    foreach (string DirName in Directory.GetDirectories(FullPath))
                    {
                        RemoveSpywareFiles("", DirName, true);
                        try { Directory.Delete(DirName); }catch { }
                    }
                }
                DInfo.Attributes = Attr;
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveSpywareFile(string FileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                try { File.Delete(FileName); }catch { }//Locked by something and you can forget trying to delete index.dat files this way
            }
        }

        private static void DeleteFireFoxFiles(string FireFoxPath)
        {
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "cookies.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "content-prefs.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "downloads.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "formhistory.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "search.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "signons.sqlite");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "search.json");
            RemoveSpywareFile(FireFoxPath + "permissions.sqlite");
        }

        public static void RunCleanup()
        {
            try { KillProcess("iexplore"); }
            catch { }//Need to stop incase they have locked the files we want to delete
            try { KillProcess("FireFox"); }
            catch { }//Need to stop incase they have locked the files we want to delete
            string RootPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal).ToLower().Replace("documents", "");
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects",false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\#local", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files", false);//Not working
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles("", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.History), true);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Wer", true);  
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches", false);          
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Temp", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\LocalLow\Apple Computer\QuickTime\downloads", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent", false);
            RemoveSpywareFiles(RootPath, @"AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache", false);
            if (Directory.Exists(RootPath + @"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"))
            {
                string FireFoxPath = RootPath + @"AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\";
                DeleteFireFoxFiles(FireFoxPath);
                foreach (string SubPath in Directory.GetDirectories(FireFoxPath))
                {
                    DeleteFireFoxFiles(SubPath + "\\");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void KillProcess(string ProcessName)
        {//We ned to kill Internet explorer and Firefox to stop them locking files
            ProcessName = ProcessName.ToLower();
            foreach (Process P in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (P.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith(ProcessName))
                    P.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the path from using this function `Environment.GetFolderPath()` with `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration. Delete all files contained in that directory while iterating over them.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this.

```
using System.IO;

public static void Main()
{
 ClearFolder(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache))); // Execute ClearFolder() on the IE's cache folder
 }

 void ClearFolder(DirectoryInfo diPath)
 {
   foreach (FileInfo fiCurrFile in diPath.GetFiles())
   {
      fiCurrFile.Delete();
   }
   foreach (DirectoryInfo diSubFolder in diPath.GetDirectories())
   {
      ClearFolder(diSubFolder); // Call recursively for all subfolders
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you and nima copy verbatim [the same search result](http://forums.asp.net/t/1563686.aspx/1)? You should provide attribution if you copy from somewhere.

Comment: I din't know about this, but I take the code from here: http://www.geekpedia.com/code166_Delete-All-Temporary-Internet-Files-Of-IE.html

Answer (score -1):

I understand you may not know how to get started, but StackOverflow is not intended to be a place where you can just turn up and request code.

In any case, a real basic bit of code to get you started would be this:

```
List<string> someFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)).ToList();
foreach (var fileName in someFiles)
    File.Delete(fileName);
```

Of course you have to consider things like access permissions, locked files, subfolders, etc.

I would suggest you start with this, then come back with further questions when you actually have some working code.